# What is the probability of having this number of elements in common between two sets?

Tags: probability

I'm not quite sure if this is a normal coloured balls from a bag problem, so go easy on me please.

I have two sets, one has 2400 elements the other 350. 47 elements occur in both. Is there a way to estimate the probability/pvalue of seeing that many in overlap by chance?

update based on comment:

The elements are genes that are differentially expressed.  So when I say set 1 has 2400, that means 2400/22k are interesting in SetA while 350/22k in B are interesting. I doubt the chance of each appearing is independent as the experimental conditions are similar. But I want to see how likely it is that they are properly related, and not just have some similar by chance.

Comment: What is an element, and how many different elements are there in total? Is the chance equal for each element to appear?

Comment: Probabilities and p-values are quite different things, but neither seems appropriate since you haven't provided any kind of probability mechanism.  So you have two sets: nothing more can be said unless you tell us how they might be used in some kind of chance mechanism.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: Ive added some more information, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

There's a little over 7.8% chance of getting an overlap as large as $x=47$ from independent samples of sizes $a=350$ and $b=2400$ of a population of size $n=22000$.  So, mildly surprising, but not enough to draw any firm conclusions.

In gory detail, the probability of overlap exactly $x$ is
$$
  \mathbb{P}(x;n,a,b) = \frac{n!x!(b-x)!(a-x)!(n+x-a-b)!}{a!b!(n-a)!(n-b)!}
$$
from which we find
$$
  \sum_{x\ge 47} \mathbb{P}(x;22000,350,2400) \ \approx \ 0.07818992
$$
Happily, I get the same result from simulation.

Comment: Since the question explicitly rules out independence, it seems odd to assume it in the answer. (On the other hand there's no basis offered on which to assume anything in particular, making the question seemingly unanswerable.)

Comment: Unless/until @pepsimax has a model for dependent behaviour, there's nothing else to be done.  It would be useful to collect more data under the same experimental conditions, then compute a $p$-value for the number of those 47 genes being "special" in the new data.  If "differentially expression" is a numeric thing, not just a "yes"/"no" Boolean, and the conditions of the experiment can be kept sufficiently stable, then a deeper analysis may be possible.

Comment: +1 The question implicitly asks for a hypothesis test in a hypergeometric setting, with the null hypothesis asserting independence.  That makes this calculation appropriate and general.